# changing a function to use parameters instead of hard coded values

Tags: javascript, function

I am using the following bit of code to create a countdown timer on my page and it works great with the exception that all the date information is hard coded into the "getSeconds" function and I was wanting to make it so I could have multiple countdowns on the same page which I am guessing means the "getSeconds" function will have to be changed to accept parameters, but I am not quite sure how to do this and thought I would ask the experts here for their help.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

var cday;
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function getSeconds() {
    var now = new Date();
    var nowtime = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
    var countdowntime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0); //  16 hrs = 4 pm
    // countdowntime - change time hh,mm,ss to whatever time required, e.g. 7,50,0 (0750)
    var dy = 0; // Friday (day 5) - change for other days 0-6
    var atime = countdowntime.getTime();
    var diff = parseInt((atime - nowtime) / 1000); // positive if date is in future
    if (diff > 0) {
        cday = dy - now.getDay();
    } else {
        cday = dy - now.getDay() - 1;
    }
    if (cday < 0) {
        cday += 7;
    } // aleady passed countdown time, so go for next week
    if (diff <= 0) {
        diff += (86400 * 7)
    }
    startTimer(diff);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
    timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
    ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
    tick(); // to start counter display right away
}

function tick() {
    var secs = timeInSecs;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeInSecs--;
    } else {
        clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
        getSeconds(); // and start all over again! 
    }
    var days = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
    secs %= 86400;
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    secs %= 3600;
    var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    secs %= 60;
    var result = "Time remaining " + cday + ' day(s) ';
    result += ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + " hours " + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + " minutes " + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs + " seconds";
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = result;
}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload = "getSeconds()">
    <span id="countdown" style="font-size: 20; font-weight:bold;"> </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you reduce the code to the minimum amount possible where we can still see the issue?

Comment: changed to show just the function in question

Comment: @JustinL.: There's no issue, he just want's to know what he needs to change. And for that we need the whole code, as it does not only include `getSeconds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple. An example:

```
function myFunction(var1,var2) {
//some code
}
```

So simple change those dates information for that variables.
When you want to call your function, use it with the arguments that you previously wrote.

**Edit:**

You could do something like that, passing each parameter separately:

```
function getSeconds(hours, minutes, seconds, daycode) {
    var now = new Date();
    var nowtime = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
    var countdowntime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), hours, minutes, seconds); //  16 hrs = 4 pm
    // countdowntime - change time hh,mm,ss to whatever time required, e.g. 7,50,0 (0750)
    var dy = daycode; // Friday (day 5) - change for other days 0-6
    var atime = countdowntime.getTime();
    var diff = parseInt((atime - nowtime) / 1000); // positive if date is in future
    if (diff > 0) {
        cday = dy - now.getDay();
    } else {
        cday = dy - now.getDay() - 1;
    }
    if (cday < 0) {
        cday += 7;
    } // aleady passed countdown time, so go for next week
    if (diff <= 0) {
        diff += (86400 * 7)
    }
    startTimer(diff);
}
```

You could also pass an object argument, something like:

```
countdown = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0); //  16 hrs = 4 pm

function getSeconds(countdown, daycode) {
    var now = new Date();
    var nowtime = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
    var countdowntime = countdown
    ...
```

Comment: I would understand that if each variable only had one value, but if you look at the countdowntime variable it contains an array so how would I do that using your example. Guess I am not following you despite how simple you made it appear.

Comment: I edited my answer.
If you want to put multiples countdowns on the webpage, simple call your function passing those multiples parameters.
In this case, where you have several functions, you could so the same process, or rewrite them passing parameters from one to another, this way you have to entry the parameters in only one function.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps someone else can make use of it. I still cannot follow it however. I voted for it since you actually spent the time on coding it and editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of passing the year, month and date as parameter, and used for you countdowntime. When you call the getSeconds function, just pass in `getSeconds(2013,7,8)`

```
function getSeconds(varYear, varMonth, varDate) {
    var now = new Date();
    var nowtime = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
    var countdowntime = new Date(varYear, varMonth, varDate, 0, 0, 0); //  16 hrs = 4 pm
    // countdowntime - change time hh,mm,ss to whatever time required, e.g. 7,50,0 (0750)
    var dy = 0; // Friday (day 5) - change for other days 0-6
    var atime = countdowntime.getTime();
    var diff = parseInt((atime - nowtime) / 1000); // positive if date is in future
    if (diff > 0) {
        cday = dy - now.getDay();
    } else {
        cday = dy - now.getDay() - 1;
    }
    if (cday < 0) {
        cday += 7;
    } // aleady passed countdown time, so go for next week
    if (diff <= 0) {
        diff += (86400 * 7)
    }
    startTimer(diff);
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't make multiple countdowns possible.

Comment: Should pass an object instead. 1 param, completely expandable over time.

Comment: @CalebC That only takes care of part of the problem as Bergi pointed out, I still need to account for the hours,mins,seconds, and the day of the week variables.

Comment: @Derek I am not following you (my JS knowledge is very limited) so an example would be most helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable `countdowntime` is the one you would need to pass in as an argument to the function getSeconds() in order to have multiple countdowns.  You would just need to change your function definition to take in that `Date` object as a parameter, like this:

```
function getSeconds(countdowntime){
```

and comment out the line currently declaring the countdowntime object. Something else I noticed, however, is that you were using global variables to share data between functions. This is something you may need to look at reworking since now there will be multiple timers.

Comment: He not only *may* need to look at that, he *must* fix those to allow multiple countdowns.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I meant :)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I guess I am over my head here since this is not my script and I have very limited knowledge in JS and it seems I have opened a can a worms with this question. I guess I will just have to find a pre-made solution that I can use. Please upvote the solution that best answers the question since I cannot get any of them to work as I need.